# Copy one model A into Model B is giving error

Tags: python, django-models, model, copy

I am trying to copy model A into Model B, but for some reason I am getting Unique Constraint Failed : appname_duplicate.id

```
Class orignal(models.Model):
  managed = True
  [some_fields]
  def __unicode__(self):
     return self.recipient_email

Class duplicate(models.Model):
  managed = True
  [same_as_Orignal_fields]
  def __unicode__(self):
     return self.recipient_email
```

Function :

```
def clone_orignal(source, destination):
    duplicate = list()
    for row in source.objects.all().values():
      if row not in duplicate:
        duplicate.append(destination(**row))
    if duplicate:
      destination.objects.bulk_create(duplicate)
```

Could someone take a look at it please?

Comment: Your function is hard to understand. Should `duplicate` be a class object or a list instance?

Comment: `source.objects.all().values` is a method; maybe you meant to call it like this `.values()` ?

Comment: What is `summary` ?

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? Should `bilk_create()` really be inside the for loop?

Comment: yes I mean .values(). It was typo.
I have changed summary to duplicate. 
@Ralf duplicate is a list which will hold orignal objects to create bulk update